# .htaccess does not activate 404 rule when entering wrong URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have some rules working fine for accessing categories/subcategories/products

But if I enter a non existing URL, instead of activate the 404 rule, access to principal.php

also for images and other extensions
How can I cancel the rules for all calls except the following ones:

- mydomain.com/MyCategory
- mydomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategoy
- mydomain.com/MyCategory/MySubcategoy/MyProduct

The rule should not apply to URL's with extensions (e.g *.html, *.css, *.php, *.pdf, etc)
And these extensions should not appear

example

> mydomain.com/contact.php

should be

> mydomain.com/contact

this is my .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 file-not-found.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^.]*\.html)/?$  $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^.]*\.php)/?$  $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&prod=$3  [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Since you are not expecting few formats(eg: html, php etc) then from your current Rules set we can remove 1 set of rules and keep it one so total would be 4 rules set.

```
ErrorDocument 404 file-not-found.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:html|css|pdf|php)/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:html|css|pdf|php)/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:html|css|pdf|php)/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:html|css|pdf|php)/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ principal.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&prod=$3  [L]
```

Comment: And how can I hide extensions?  Tried this but not working fine
                                           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

Comment: @Jam, could you please give few examples here, I am cooking as of now but can take s look to it, cheers.